# Fedora: Changing Mono version with Mono Develop

Tags: mono, monodevelop, fedora

Running Fedora, I installed MonoDevelop via flatpak as detailed on their [website](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/). I now found out that MD was running with Mono 5.4.1. According to `flatpak update`, no updates are available for MD.  Since I noticed some errors while building projects, I updated Mono to the latest version 5.10 by installing the project's reposity as explained on [Mono's website](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-fedora).

As expected, `mono --version` now outputs `Mono JIT compiler version 5.10.1.20`.

However, Mono Develop is still using Mono 5.4 according to the "About" page. I wanted to change the runtime by hand (maybe flatpak packs its own runtime, I thought), but trying to add the current mono runtime via `Edit -> Preferences... -> Projects -> .NET Runtimes` in MD fails, as no `mono` can be found in `/usr/bin`, though that's exactly where `which mono` describes it installed.

So now I have two questions:

1. How can I make MonoDevelop use the new Mono version?
2. Where is this Mono 5.4 located MD claims to be using?

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop flatpak deployment has some issues that are not easy to fix, which require manpower that it seems the team doesn't have at the moment. That's why they have switched, in the meantime, to old-school packaging and you can install MonoDevelop again via DEB/RPM instead of flatpak.

Grab the packages from here: https://www.monodevelop.com/download/#fndtn-download-lin-centos